# Websphere liberty: Timer Manager

Tags: websphere, websphere-liberty

I am migrating application from WebSphere to liberty.
It uses WebSphere timer managers.

What is the use of timer manager? 
Is this supported in liberty. Is it the same as timer service in liberty?

Answer (score 0):

Liberty does not have TimerManager, but it has similarly capability for scheduling tasks via the EE Concurrency spec-defined [javax.enterprise.concurrent.ManagedScheduledExecutorService](https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/enterprise/concurrent/ManagedScheduledExecutorService.html), which is provided by the Liberty concurrent-1.0 feature.  A [knowledge center page](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/twlp_config_scheduledexecutor.html) includes some examples and describes how to configure. Another knowledge center page provides helpful information on [migrating to EE Concurrency from CommonJ or AsyncBeans](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSD28V_liberty/com.ibm.websphere.wlp.core.doc/ae/rwlp_migrate_to_eeconcurrency.html).

To answer you question about the difference between timer manager and timer service, timer service typically refers to the EJB Timer Service, which has a mechanism to schedule persistent and non-persistent timers.  EJB non-persistent timers are another alternative in Liberty to the CommonJ TimerManager, if you happen to be using EJBs. Otherwise, ManagedScheduledExecutorService can be used regardless of whether or not you use EJBs.  Both provide mechanisms for scheduling timers/tasks for execution in the future, where the timers/tasks do not persist across server start and do not have the ability to be rolled back and retried (those are additional value that is provided by EJB persistent timers).